# Convert synchronous function to async function in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I want to convert a (relatively) slow event handler to `async` to avoid blocking the other event subscribers. In the example below I do not want the other subscribers to the `Message` event to have to wait.

The only thing I can think of looks like "cheating":

```
client.Message += async (object sender, MessageEventArgs e) => {
    await Task.Run(() => { });
    logger.Info("Some info {0}", e.Message);
}
```

Of course I could wrap the whole `logger.Info` call in the `Task`, but I don't see why that is better. I just looks less like cheating.

My only other thought is that the handler should be left synchronous, and the `Message` event should only be subscribed to when latency is not critical. So I could have a second event that is only used by low latency `async` subscribers.

I am looking for feedback on the proper coding design here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219315/discussion-on-question-by-james-hirschorn-convert-synchronous-function-to-async).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Task.Yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield) if you want to attach an asynchronous handler that will be invoked after all synchronous handlers of the same event have been invoked, and you also want the asynchronous invocation to occur on the current synchronization context. For a GUI application this means that you want the handler to run on the UI thread.

```
client.Message += async (sender, e) =>
{
    await Task.Yield();
    logger.Info("Some info {0}", e.Message);
}
```

Don't use `await Task.Run(() => { })`, because it's just a verbose, idiomatic, less efficient and (possibly) less robust alternative of `await Task.Yield()`.

If you want to attach an asynchronous handler that will run on a `ThreadPool` thread (instead of the current synchronization context), use [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run):

```
client.Message += async (sender, e) =>
{
    await Task.Run(() => logger.Info("Some info {0}", e.Message));
}
```

You should only do that if you are sure that the `logger` object is thread-safe, supports concurrent operations, and doesn't require thread-affinity (like many COM components do).

Comment: Perhaps I should update my question, but there is still one thing I am not clear on: My understanding is that the `logger.Info` call takes a negligible amount of time. Yet I noticed a measurable delay, in other tasks in the current synchronization context,  when the above handler was synchronous instead of `async`. So the question is: does it still make sense performance-wise to use an `async` handler for an operation that takes a negligible amount of time?

Comment: @James Hirschorn the behavior you are observing is quite inexplicable, and the workaround you discovered is equally surprising that it works. Having an inexplicable problem that is fixed by an inexplicable solution is not good news for the long term maintainability of your application. I suggest that you update your question with more info about the problem, so that we have a better idea about what's going on. How much is the delay when attaching the sync handler, how much is when attaching the async handler, and how did you measure it?

Comment: I am also weary of inexplicable solutions. I will need to investigate further, and perhaps ask a new question once the performance issues become more clear.